# Generic Singly-Linked List implementation

Tags: c#, beginner, .net, linked-list, reinventing-the-wheel

I'm looking for some feedback regarding my implementation of a generic singly-linked list in C#. I'm also looking for some tips on how to implement other techniques such as using `IEnumerable` or other .NET interfaces I'm currently not aware of.

Node.cs

```c
using System; 
namespace SinglyLinkedLists
{
    public class Node<T>
    {
        private Node<T> _next;
        private T _data;

        public Node<T> next{
            get { return _next; }
            set { _next = value; }
        }

        public T data{
            get { return _data; }
            set { _data = value; }
        }

        public Node(T newData){
            this._data = newData;
            this._next = null; 
        }

        public static void printNodes(Node<T> head){
            Node<T> currentNode = head;
            while (currentNode != null){
                Console.WriteLine(currentNode.data);
                currentNode = currentNode.next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SinglyLinkedLists.cs

```c
using System; 
namespace SinglyLinkedLists
{
    public class SinglyLinkedLists<T>
    {
        private Node<T> head;
        private Node<T> previous;
        private Node<T> current;
        private Node<T> tail;

        private int numberOfNodes = 0;

        public SinglyLinkedLists()
        {
            head = null;
            previous = null;
            current = null;
            tail = null; 
        }

        public void PrintList(){
            Node<T> current = head;
            while (current != null){
                Console.WriteLine(current.data);
                current = current.next;
            }
        }

        public void AddLast(T data){
            Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(data);
            if (tail == null){
                head = tail = newNode;
            }
            else{
                tail.next = newNode; 
                tail = newNode; 
            }
            numberOfNodes++;
        }

        public void AddLastTwo(T data){
            Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(data);

            if (head == null){
                head = newNode; 
            }
            else{
                current = head;
                while (current.next != null){
                    current = current.next; 
                }
                current.next = newNode;
            }
            numberOfNodes++;
        }

        public void RemoveNode(T data){
            Node<T> nodeToRemove = new Node<T>(data);
            current = head;

            if(head.data.Equals(nodeToRemove.data)){
                current = head.next;
                head = current;
            }
            else{
                while (current != null){
                    if (current.data.Equals(nodeToRemove.data)) {
                        previous.next = current.next;
                        current = previous;
                    }
                    else{
                        previous = current;
                        current = current.next;
                    }
                }
            }
            numberOfNodes--;
        }

        public int ListSize(){
            return numberOfNodes;
        }

        public bool InList(T data){
            Node<T> nodeToLookFor = new Node<T>(data);
            Node<T> current = head;
            while (current != null){
                if (current.data.Equals(nodeToLookFor.data)){
                    return true;
                }
                current = current.next;
            }
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: _I'm also looking for some tips on how to implement [..]_ - You should remove this request from your question as it makes it off-topic because we are not implementing new features for you. But if you already know about `IEnumerable` why don't you add it yourself?

Answer (score 2):

A few things that stuck out to me:

You don't gain anything by having the `Node` class public.  The user of your linked list should only need to be concerned about the data.

It seems very illogical to me to have the `Node` class printing the `LinkedList`.  This should more properly be only part of the `LinkedList` itself.  It would probably be advantageous though for the `Node` class to override the `ToString()` method to make it easier to print the data.

From a quick perusal, I couldn't see any use for the `previous` property except in the `RemoveNode` method.  I would suggest keeping it local to that method.

A comment explaining the purpose of the `AddLastTwo` method.  To me it appears to iterate over the list to find the last node, instead of using the `last` property of the class, like the `AddLast`.

To me names like `AddLast` and `RemoveNode` are over complicated.  If a node isn't being added to the end then it would be an insert operation not an add.  It shouldn't be necessary to tell the user that it's being added to the end.  Likewise the user doesn't need to know that the data is stored in a node, they are simply concerned with removing the data.

When you are using default `get` and `set` methods it's much easier to use the default syntax:

```
public Node<T> next{get;set;}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a small answer but is kind of important in my opinion. `bool InList(T data)` and `int ListSize()` are existing patterns among .Net classes, they should be named `Contains` and `Count`. The lesson to come out of this is that you should try to reuse common names when the pattern fits.

Also, your class name shouldn't be pluralized. `SinglyLinkedLists` -> `SinglyLinkedList`